# how to use uiv module in nuxt.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, plugins, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have installed the module and add the below code in plugin folder

// uiv.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as uiv from 'uiv'

Vue.use(uiv)
```

> How to use it in component in nuxt i don't know please help me hear, it's works in vue.js

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps:

1. Download the compiled CSS and JavaScript Bootstrap files of the version you are interested it (for example, for the current **Bootstrap v4.3.1** you can download those files [from here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/))
2. Uncompress the file you got. Open the result folder. You will see then 2 subfolders: **js** and **css**. Go into **css** folder and copy the file called **boostrap.min.css** into the **~/assets** folder of your Nuxt.js project
3. Go back to your **~/plugins/uiv.js** file and update it this way:

   ```
   import '@/assets/bootstrap.min.css'                                                                                                                                     

   import Vue from 'vue'                                                                                                                                                   
   import * as uiv from 'uiv'                                                                                                                                              

   Vue.use(uiv)
   ```

   As you can see, you have to update only the first `import` statement to point to the location of our **bootstrap.min.css** file.
4. Open **nuxt.config.js** file which is on the root of your project folder. Search for the key called `plugins` and add your **uiv.js** plugin there:

   ```
   plugins: [                                                                                                                                                            
     '@/plugins/uiv.js'                                                                                                                                                  
   ],
   ```
5. To make sure you followed the above steps correctly, open any of your **.vue** files (let's say **~/pages/index.vue** file) and add this line:

   ```
   <btn type="primary">Primary</btn>
   ```
6. Re-lunch your server: `yarn run dev`
7. You should get something like this:

[image]